# How to stabilize a loose/failing USB connection?

Tags: technology, plastics

I always end up having a 'USB device not recognised' error while I fix my external harddisk to my laptop. Even a slight disturbance causes this error due to the weight of the disk, and I find it really difficult to move around with my laptop fixed to the hard disk.

[image]
[image]

I was thinking of making an enclosure which could be 3D printed and fixed as a cap to the USB port of the hard-disk so that it could then be clamped onto the laptop. However, for clamping onto the laptop's flat surface there should be a mechanism that makes it sturdy, so that there is no movement of the USB which leads to the connection error.

The enclosure should also be able to be firm when the cable is **yanked** in any direction.

Comment: The only solution I have found so far was to replace the computer or the hard disk drive. If yours is still working when plugged in, put them together on a table and leave them there as long as you need that connection.

Answer (score 1):

You have to first know if the bad connection is at the usb plug or of its on the hard drive enclosure. Test the plug on other devices if it still fails cut off the plug and solder a new plug on or replace cable, if no problems with the cable its the hard disk enclosure. If the hard disk can be removed you can buy a cheap laptop hard drive enclosure to swap the hard disk over to ($15 on amazon or ebay or newegg). If you cannot easily remove it , back up the data just in case and destroy the enclosure to rip out the hard disk. Most likely it will still work but in case the connections are proprietary you have your backup. The other thing before taking out the hard drive is see if the pins that the usb plug connects to are bent inwards, use a metal pick to bend the pins out to make better contact with usb plug

Answer (score 0):

You can try connecting a **usb extension cable** to your original faulty usb port. Then connect your hard disk through the extension. This way the forces on the faulty plug may reduce.

Note that if this disconnection issue persists, it can be problematic for the health of your external HDD. Be sure to take a **backup** of its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a new connecting cable. A longer one if at all possible.

Every time I've had this problem with usb connections, the cable itself started getting hot after a while. An extension cable will not fix that nor will trying to rig the connection point.

Pay for a new cable now or a new laptop/drive (and possible data loss.)
Your choice.

Answer (score -2):

hardly press front of your USB cable that should be closer.

than after plug your USB to your computer it should don`t loose.

Comment: The wording on this answer makes it very confusing. Could you please clear this up?