# How to remove water from under a layer of homemade yogurt?

Tags: water

It's a plastic jar with commercially made soymilk, I add a culture and then it turns into yogurt. The problem is the water that separates and sits under the layer of yogurt. I tried using a straw to remove water but I really hate it when water gets in my mouth. Any other ways you can think of?

Edit: Please someone unlock the question. It definitely belongs here.

[image]

Comment: This is a much better fit for our [Cooking site](http://cooking.stackexchange.com). They deal with these types of issues every day, but this type of *"how to"* is off topic for this site. Good luck!

Comment: There can be anything instead of yogurt, it's not about yogurt, it's about removing liquid from under something.

Comment: You can't generally ask an overly generic hypothetical question and expect a solution that works in all possible situations. Ask about a problem you actually have, and this one is a good fit for Cooking SE.

Comment: You are being biased towards me. Last time it was  too specific, now it's too generic. This is not a good fit for cooking because it's not part of cooking process. Please educate yourself.

Comment: @RobertCartaino how come this one is not on hold and not recommended for the superuser section? 
https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15608/how-to-stabilize-a-loose-failing-usb-connection